# Get all records of user if one has certain value

Tags: looker-studio

I have table in Google DataStudio:

```
1.  Mike     Apple
2.  Jane     Peach
3.  Anna     Apple
4.  Mike     Mango
```

I want to filter table by term 'Apple' so the result would be like that:

```
1.  Mike     Apple
3.  Anna     Apple
4.  Mike     Mango
```

If the user has Apple it should show all records of current user. How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible with a blend (but I did not test it):

1. Use your table as the first (left) table of the blend filtered by Apple.
2. Include only names in the first table of the blend.
3. Use the same table as the 2nd (right) table of the blend, without any filters.